# Drupal 8 custom block output becoming blank after clearing cache

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8, drupal-theming, drupal-blocks

I have created custom block in drupal 8 using custom module.
Assigned a twig template ( located in active theme ).
I am passing some custom theme_settings to twig template using theme_get_setting() method.
Everything works perfect.
But once i clear drupal cache, The variables i am passing to twig template are getting NULL values, and only static HTML is rendered, But same theme settings are populated correctly in drupal dashboard.

Comment: I found that if i add die() statement in my custom module, then clear cache then remove die() and then reload page then twig starts showing dynamic data. so I guesss my module is not getting loaded / executed on each page request.